# fadeToggle working with a toggle function

Tags: jquery

here's my code :

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').click(function() {
$("#retouche_a_faire_alert").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

It's working great. Basicly, it's a function that makes a `div` appear when the "retouche_a_faire" checkbox is checked, and disapear when it's not. But I would like to use the `fadeToggle` option instead of `toggle`. How can I make this work?

I tried :

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').click(function() {
$("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeToggle(this.checked);
});
```

But it's not working, since I need to set the duration and easing I think...but I need to use "this.checked" in the parantheses too...I'm a bit confused.

Thank you!

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a6Dkw/4/

In this case you don't want to use fadeToggle() unless you know for a fact it will start out as `display:none`, it is much safer to test to see if it is checked. Also if you are using jQuery 1.7.2, you can use `.on('click')` and `.prop()`

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeOut();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

fadeToggle does not have a boolean option, but you can use fadeOut/fadeIn based on the checkbox like this:

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeIn( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] );
    } else {
        $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In its basic form:

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').click(function() {
  $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").fadeToggle();
});
```

If you want to use `.fadeToggle()` you could run a check onload to show hide the alert depending on if its checkbox is checked:

```
if (!$("#retouche_a_faire").attr('checked'))
    $("#retouche_a_faire_alert").hide();
```

See my example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Y2cnR/

**Update**
I've updated my fiddle to show applying my answer to multiple inputs - http://jsfiddle.net/Y2cnR/1/

Comment: Problem is you won't know whether to show / or hide it and might get reverse effects than desired

Comment: When you wrote this comment i had said in my answer "In its basic form". There was no checking in my answer, so your comment wasnt valid.

Comment: Very true, I didn't mean it in a negative way! I was only saying. Apologies.

Comment: I think stackoverflow should tag a comment to a revision in the answer, that way users can tell at what state the answer was at when the comment was made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean value with fadeTo for example

```
$('#retouche_a_faire').click(function() { 
    $('#retouche_a_faire_alert').stop().fadeTo(200,this.checked ? 1 : 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqD5C/1/